# Qt Doesn't compile anything on mac

Tags: c++, qt, clang, clang++, qmake

hey guys I just updated my mac to monterey 12.1 and then my qt creator doesn't compile anything any part of code no deference non console app or non widget app or any other types and just telling me the same error:

```
:-1: error: No rule to make target `untitled6'.  Stop.

:-1: warning: "/.../.../CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang" is used by qmake, but 
     "/usr/bin/clang" is configured in the kit.
     Please update your kit (Replacement for "Qt 6.2.0 for macOS") or choose a mkspec
     for qmake that matches your target environment better.

:-1: warning: "/.../.../CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang++" is used by qmake,
     but "/usr/bin/clang++" is configured in the kit.
     Please update your kit (Replacement for "Qt 6.2.0 for macOS") or choose a mkspec
     for qmake that matches your target environment better.
```

I try to build new projects and new codes and check my paths and also uninstall and install again the qt but non of them worked and it gave me the same error. I had read the errors but I can't figure out what should I do with my kits!

this is my confige page:

[image: confige]

What should I do?

Comment: Did you have these warnings before ? If not, I am not sure but I think this update added clang in path (I did the same update), but this is just a warning that tells you that Qt has its own version of clang and found an other one in path. You just have to put clang from Qt in $PATH before so it is taken instead of the one in `/usr/bin/clang` (txpe `which clang` to see which clang is taken, it takes the one that it finds first in $PATH)

The error is more concerning here, can you show us your project config window ?

Comment: hey Dardan Iljazi no I didn't have this error before! also yes the second and third part are warnings that came after the first part and that is my error and i didn't find any solution for any of them

Comment: also I add my config to the Q for you

Comment: I just saw your message, have you found a solution since ?
I see that under `compiler` - `C` and `C++` you have the path going to `/usr/bin/clang`, try to change these to point to `/.../.../CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang` (I think this folder is in Qt Editor or Qt folder, you have to look at it I'm not sure where it is).

Comment: me too buddy and also not only i don't know where it is i can't find it and also no idea how to change this path cause it just let me choose from it list :)

Comment: What compilers do you have in the compiler tab?

Comment: c(clang (c, x86 32bit at usr/bin/clang),clang (c, x86 64bit at usr/bin/clang),clang (c, x86 32bit at users/user/qt/.../clang),clang (c, x86 64bit at users/user/qt/.../clang),apple clang(x86_64),apple clang(armv7),apple clang(arm64),apple clang(i386),apple clang(armv7k))

Comment: c++(clang (c++, x86 32bit at usr/bin/clang++),clang (c++, x86 64bit at usr/bin/clang++),apple clang(x86_64),apple clang(armv7),apple clang(arm64),apple clang(i386),apple clang(armv7k))
manual c 
manual c++

Answer (score 0):

1. Manually delete the hidden folder `.qmake.stash` in your build folder from the terminal
2. Run `qmake` from Qt Creator
3. Build as normal

(A manual `make distclean`in the build directory should also fix it, but I never tried that)

Comment: can you explain more? where is the build folder in my projects folder or in qt installed path or etc?

Comment: Qt Creater puts the build folder wherever you tell it to and names it something like ´build <Project Name><Environment>`. You should find it right next to your source folder. So, if your source folder is, for example `/home/Documents/C/myProject`, the build folder would be something along the lines of `/home/documents/C/buidMyProject-Desktop_Qt_6_2_2_clang_64bit_Debug`

Comment: ok I did it and again got stock with this error